# Are the encoded messages different for the same plain text but different modulus in RSA?

Tags: rsa, asymmetric

I am trying to reproduce the RSA attack in which the CRT is used for an exponent of e=3 and no padding. I want to code the same plain message (i.e. "HI") with three different public keys, (e1,n1) (e2,n2) (e3,n3). However, I get c1=c2=c3 equal, although n1!=n2!=n3. The three RSA exponents are e1=e2=e3=3.

However if I use a bigger plain text(i.e "Hi my name is "), the three codes are then different c1!=c2!=c3

Is this normal behavior? Why is happening?

Also, when I perform the CRT operation, I can only recover  "Hi my", instead the whole string. Is there any limitation in the size of m? Or am I messing myself with precision or type conversion?

The example is:

Pub key 1: 3

```
521319240222107884689410763002651770477
```

Pub key 2: 3

```
971942073666717835868044797161302855351
```

Pub key 3: 3

```
1130117127193245273914627104538121346723
```

I am going to code: "Hi my name is"

check `m0=5736962829656840785174168889715`

Code1:

```
189327048722959219131229293322701756239
```

Code2:

```
655706385250016486665327564357017094773
```

Code3:

```
109975795916415293594862048607166887857
```

the m I got after the calculation is: `m1=5736962829656818723003509506048`
which m0!=m1

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be better suited to [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).  Still, you are not considering that you may be making mistakes in your calculation.  It would be much better to describe (even verbosely) the steps you are taking instead of the results.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting mad. Now I know it is normal I can sleep ;-)
I still have the problem with the non-matching messages m0!=m1, however I think its only a problem with the precision in Python. Using a string up to 6 characters works fine. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sufficiently small m and e, yes, the ciphertexts will be the same. What's more, they can be trivially decrypted.

As you say, you're not using any padding. RSA needs to be used with padding; it is not secure to encrypt unpadded values that are much smaller than the modulus size (`m < n^(1/e)`, i.e. your message is less than the cube root of your modulus).

From Wikipedia:

> When encrypting with low encryption exponents (e.g., e = 3) and small values of the m, (i.e., m < n^1/e) the result of m^e is strictly less than the modulus n. In this case, ciphertexts can be easily decrypted by taking the eth root of the ciphertext over the integers.

This implies that the ciphertexts (*m^e mod n*) are going to be the same for very small messages, yes. If *m^e < n1*, *n2*, and *n3*, then **(m^e mod n1) = (m^e mod n2) = (m^e mod n3) = m^e**, and you can recover m by raising it to 1/e (taking the eth root).

See [Attacks against plain RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Attacks_against_plain_RSA) and check out [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) for the usual padding algorithm.